# SQL Select inner join 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have some tables, let's call them table `UserManagement`

```
ID  Username Position
1   Bryan    Client
2   Frey     Client
3   Will     Vendor
4   Anne     Vendor
5   Belle    Vendor
```

And this is table `Mailbox`

```
ID  FromUser ToUser           Message
1   Bryan    Will,Anne,Belle  Hai
2   Anne     Bryan,Frey       Hello
```

I've been try this:

```
select * from Mailbox t
inner join (select Username from UserManagement where Position = 'Client' group by Username)um
on t.ToUser = um.Username
```

But it's work when column `ToUser` contain only Username `Bryan` or `Frey` not with `Bryan,Frey`
How to solve that when column `ToUser` contain Username like `Bryan,Frey`?

Comment: ```ToUser``` is a string, therefore if you compare two strings you wont get what you want. I recommend you to make ```ToUser``` column contain only one name

Comment: You'll need to split the string using a function like `STRING_SPLIT` to use the data effectively in a relational query. A proper relational database model avoids repeating values in a column ([first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)), and makes querying much easier. Consider creating another table with one row per ToUser.

Comment: Why Bryan and Frey are in the same columns, I would say its a bad design and aagainst the basics of 1st Normal form of DBMS.

Comment: You can try `t.ToUser LIKE  CONCAT('%', um.Username ,'%')` instead of `t.ToUser = um.Username`

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single string column.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a query which splits the ToUser column from the Mailbox table in the 'mb_split_cte' CTE.  Then it joins to the UserManagement table on Username.  Then it returns the management positions of the ToUsers from the Mailbox table.

Data

```
DECLARE @Mailbox TABLE(ID int identity(1,1),
                       FromUser varchar(150),
                       ToUser varchar(150),
                       [Message] varchar(250));

INSERT INTO @Mailbox(FromUser, ToUser, [Message])
VALUES('Bryan', 'Will,Anne,Belle', 'Hai'),
('Anne', 'Bryan,Frey', 'Hello');

DECLARE @UserManagement TABLE(ID int identity(1,1),
                       Username varchar(150),
                       Position varchar(150));

INSERT INTO @UserManagement(Username, Position) VALUES
('Bryan', 'Client'),
('Frey', 'Client'),
('Will', 'Vendor'),
('Anne', 'Vendor'),
('Belle', 'Vendor');
```

Query

```
;with mb_split_cte(ID, FromUser, ToUser, [Message]) as (
    select ID, FromUser, sp.[value], [Message]
    from @Mailbox m
         cross apply string_split(m.ToUser, ',') sp)
select msc.*, um.Position as ToUserPosition
from mb_split_cte msc
     join @UserManagement um on msc.ToUser=um.Username;
```

Output

```
ID  FromUser    ToUser  Message ToUserPosition
1   Bryan       Will    Hai     Vendor
1   Bryan       Anne    Hai     Vendor
1   Bryan       Belle   Hai     Vendor
2   Anne        Bryan   Hello   Client
2   Anne        Frey    Hello   Client
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please read Dan's Guzman comment to your question. He recommends to use [STRING_SPLIT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which is very good, but this function is unavailable in MS SQL Server 2014 and older. See: [Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15)

To get `Mailbox` data splitted by comma into rows per each `ToUser`, you can use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). See:

```
DECLARE @Mailbox TABLE(ID int identity(1,1),  FromUser varchar(150),  ToUser varchar(150), [Message] varchar(250))
INSERT INTO @Mailbox(FromUser, ToUser, [Message])
VALUES('Bryan', 'Will,Anne,Belle', 'Hai'),
('Anne', 'Bryan,Frey', 'Hello')

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    --initial query
    SELECT ID, FromUser, LEFT(ToUser, CHARINDEX(',', ToUser)-1) ToUser, RIGHT(ToUser, LEN(ToUser) - CHARINDEX(',', ToUser)) remainder,  [Message]
    FROM @Mailbox
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',', ToUser)>0
    --recursive part
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, FromUser, LEFT(remainder, CHARINDEX(',', remainder)-1) ToUser, RIGHT(remainder, LEN(remainder) - CHARINDEX(',', remainder)) remainder,  [Message]
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',', remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, FromUser, remainder ToUser, NULL remainder,  [Message]
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',', remainder)=0
)
SELECT ID, FromUser, ToUser, [Message]
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY ID
```

Above query produces:

```
ID  FromUser    ToUser  Message
1   Bryan   Will    Hai
1   Bryan   Anne    Hai
1   Bryan   Belle   Hai
2   Anne    Bryan   Hello
2   Anne    Frey    Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used your SQL code and modified it slightly. Why dont you try it like this?

```
select * from Mailbox t
inner join (select Username from UserManagement where Position = 'Vendor' group by Username)um
on t.ToUser like '%'+um.Username
```